# RXJS - Filter appears to filter, but results still show unfiltered

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I am using RXJS 6.3.3.

I have the following code that should filter out the gizmos that were already selected.

So if I have:

```
Gizmos = "Red", "Blue", "Green"
```

And the user selects "Blue".

I should only see "Red" and "Green" as my available options.

However I am still seeing "Red", "Blue", "Green".

In debug it appears that the filter is working it the example it will print:

```
Red:true Blue:false Green:true
```

I am not sure what I am missing because the UI still shows all 3 values.

```
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let gizmp of filterGizmos | async" [value]="gizmo.value" (onSelectionChange)="gizmoSelectionChange(gizmo)">
          {{gizmo.value}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>



   filterGizmos: Observable<Gizmo[]>;
   this.filterGizmos = this.filterGizmoData(this.searchTerm.value); 

   filterGizmoData(searchString?: string): Observable<Gizmo[]> {
    let tfp = new GizmoFindParameters();

    if (searchString == undefined) {
      tfp.value = "";
    } else {
      tfp.value = searchString.trim();
    }

    return this.gizmoService.find<Gizmo[]>(tfp)
      .pipe(tap(x =>
        x.filter((y) => {
          console.log(y.value);
          console.log(!this.selectedGizmos.includes(y.value)); 
          return !this.selectedGizmos.includes(y.value);
        })
      )
      );
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tap` does not modify the stream. It is often used for debugging and for side effects (operations that don't affect the stream).

Use `map` instead.

This is from the documentation for `tap`:

> Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but
>   return an Observable that is identical to the source.

Comment: Thanks you.  I didnt catch that